# Map to JSON in Java

Tags: java, json

i have a map like this 
MAP:

```
{ 
  facility-1={
    facility-kind1={param1=XPath-1, param2=XPath-2}, 
    facility-kind2={param1=XPath-1, param2=XPath-2}, 
    facility-kind3={param1=XPath-1, param2=XPath-2}
  },
  facility-2={
    facility-kind1={param1=XPath-1, param2=XPath-2}, 
    facility-kind2={param1=XPath-1, param2=XPath-2}, 
    facility-kind3={param1=XPath-1, param2=XPath-2}
  }
}
```

I want to convert it into JSON formated like this

```
[

    {"title": "Item 1"},
    {"title": "Folder 2",
        "children": [
            {"title": "Sub-item 2.1"},
            {"title": "Sub-item 2.2"}
        ]
    },
    {"title": "Folder 3",
        "children": [
            {"title": "Sub-item 3.1"},
            {"title": "Sub-item 3.2"}
        ]
    },
    {"title": "Item 5"}
]
```

I tried to use GSON But the resulting output was not what I wanted:

```
{
  "facility-1": {
     "facility-kind1":
      {"param1":"XPath-1","param2":"XPath-2"},
     "facility-kind2":
      {"param1":"XPath-1","param2":"XPath-2"},
     "facility-kind3":
      {"param1":"XPath-1","param2":"XPath-2"}
  },
  "facility-2": { 
     "facility-kind1":
      {"param1":"XPath-1","param2":"XPath-2"},
     "facility-kind2":
      {"param1":"XPath-1","param2":"XPath-2","param3":"XPath-3"},
     "facility-kind3":
      {"param1":"XPath-1","param2":"XPath-2"}
  }
}
```

how can a get a json formated as i want??

Comment: Are you asking how to include the whiespace?

Comment: i want the children to be under ' "children": [ .. ] '

Comment: This might be a little offtopic, but if you want to prettyprint JSON, you can try http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: i don't want to prettyprint " i want the child elements to be under ' "children": [ .. ] ' "

Comment: There are no "children" in the source data? There are no connection between the two formats, your "format" includes items and sub-items (children) but your `"facility"` doesn't have this... You need to provide more information.

Comment: [

    {"title": "Item 1"},
    {"title": "Folder 2",
        "children": [
            {"title": "Sub-item 2.1"},
            {"title": "Sub-item 2.2"}
        ]
    },
    {"title": "Folder 3",
        "children": [
            {"title": "Sub-item 3.1"},
            {"title": "Sub-item 3.2"}
        ]
    },
    {"title": "Item 5"}
]
this was jsut a sample code
the actual result would be like
[
{"title" : "facility-1", "children":[      
     { "title":"facility-kind1"....

Comment: Then re-write your question to that and you will get lots of good answers... No one could have guessed that! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to transform your JSON to the new format you have provided.

### Data to convert:

```
static String json = 
    "{\n" + 
    "  facility-1={\n" + 
    "    facility-kind1={param1=XPath-1, param2=XPath-2},\n" +  
    "    facility-kind2={param1=XPath-1, param2=XPath-2},\n" + 
    "    facility-kind3={param1=XPath-1, param2=XPath-2}\n" + 
    "  },\n" + 
    "  facility-2={\n" + 
    "    facility-kind1={param1=XPath-1, param2=XPath-2},\n" +  
    "    facility-kind2={param1=XPath-1, param2=XPath-2},\n" +  
    "    facility-kind3={param1=XPath-1, param2=XPath-2}\n" + 
    "  }\n" + 
    "}\n";
```

### Using GSON

Create some classes that you want to handle the data, they can look something like:

```
static class Facility {
    List<Kind> children = new LinkedList<Kind>();
}

static class Kind {
    String title;
    Map<String, String> params;

    public Kind(String title, Map<String, String> params) {
        this.title = title;
        this.params = params;
    }
}
```

The next step is too look at the source and create a represenatation of it. I would use:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>
```

since the input data is layed out like it. To convert it using `Gson` now is quite easy:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    Type type = new TypeToken<
            Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>>() {}.getType();

    Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>> source = 
        gson.fromJson(json, type);

    Map<String, Facility> dest = new HashMap<String, Facility>();

    for (String facilityName : source.keySet()) {
        Map<String, Map<String, String>> facility = source.get(facilityName);

        Facility f = new Facility();

        for (String kindName : facility.keySet())
            f.children.add(new Kind(kindName, facility.get(kindName)));

        dest.put(facilityName, f);
    }

    System.out.println(gson.toJson(dest));
}
```

---

### Using JSONObject/JSONArray

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

    JSONObject source = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONArray destination = new JSONArray();

    for (Iterator<?> keys = source.keys(); keys.hasNext(); ) {

        String facilityName = (String) keys.next();
        JSONObject kinds = source.getJSONObject(facilityName);

        JSONArray children = new JSONArray();
        for (Iterator<?> kit = kinds.keys(); kit.hasNext(); ) {

            String kind = (String) kit.next();
            JSONObject params = kinds.getJSONObject(kind);

            JSONObject kindObject = new JSONObject();
            kindObject.put("title", kind);

            for (Iterator<?> pit = params.keys(); pit.hasNext(); ) {
                String param = (String) pit.next();
                kindObject.put(param, params.get(param));
            }
            children.put(kindObject);
        }

        JSONObject facility = new JSONObject();
        facility.put("title", facilityName);
        facility.put("children", children);
        destination.put(facility);
    }
    System.out.println(destination.toString(2));
}
```

Comment: i am not getiing the inner child in "children["tag   "params": {
                        "Outlet pressure-Oil(S_12448/2)": "prod3653_2/S_12448/2",
                        "Inlet pressure-Oil(S_12862/2)": "prodml653_1/S_12862/2"
                    }

Comment: Can you provide some full example data? It seems that you have some kind of recusive inner child definition. Not like you provided in your question.

Comment: [

    {"title": "Item 1"},

    {"title": "Folder 2", "isFolder": true, "key": "folder2",

        "children": [

            {"title": "Sub-item 2.1", "children": [

           {"title": "Sub-item 2.1.1","param":"something"},

           {"title": "Sub-item 2.2.1"}

       ]},

     {"title": "Sub-item 2.2"}

   ]

        },

 {"title": "Folder 3", "isFolder": true, "key": "folder3",

     "children": [

      {"title": "Sub-item 3.1"},

      {"title": "Sub-item 3.2"}

      ]

  },

 {"title": "Item 5"}

]

this is how i want o/p

Comment: But what is the input? The input provided in your question has nothing to do with for example "folders" and "key".

Answer (score 0):

What you want is pretty printing.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String json = gson.toJson(yourMap);
```

Comment: i want the children to be under ' "children": [ .. ] '