# Map to JSON with children under "children": [ .. ] JAVA

Tags: java, json

I have a map like this :

```
 { 
     facility-1={facility-kind1={param1=XPath-1, param2=XPath-2}, 
            facility-kind2={param1=XPath-1, param2=XPath-2}
           },
    facility-2={facility-kind1={param1=XPath-1, param2=XPath-2}, 
            facility-kind2={param1=XPath-1, param2=XPath-2}
         }
  }
```

I want to format it to `JSON` with the children under  "children": [ .. ] tag:

```
[
{"title": "Item 1"},

{"title": "Folder 2",
    "children": [
        {"title": "Sub-item 2.1"},
    {"title": "Sub-item 2.2"}
        ]
    },

{"title": "Folder 3",
    "children": [

        {"title": "Sub-item 3.1"},

        {"title": "Sub-item 3.2"}

        ]

    }
]
```

When I use `JSON` I don't get the children tag :

```
{
    "facility-1": {
        "facility-kind1": {
            "param1": "XPath-1",
            "param2": "XPath-2"
        },
        "facility-kind2": {
            "param1": "XPath-1",
            "param2": "XPath-2"
        }
    },
    "facility-2": {
        "facility-kind1": {
            "param1": "XPath-1",
            "param2": "XPath-2"
        },
        "facility-kind2": {
            "param1": "XPath-1",
            "param2": "XPath-2"
        }
    }
}
```

Which is not what I want.

How can I get a `JSON` formatted the way I want?

Comment: There are no children in the map?

Comment: facility-1={ specifies the child in the map

Comment: possible duplicate of [Map to JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925874/map-to-json-in-java) (your own question)

Comment: What library are you using to create the JSON?